# Script for monitoring CPU

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, freeswitch, pbx

I need to create some kind of script/runnable file for monitoring my Freeswitch PBX on Windows Server 2012 that:

1. checks a number of calls each ~5s and then writes in into a file,
2. checks % of CPU usage at that point and also writes it (into second column).

For the first part, I figured out how to check for actual number of calls flowing through:

```
fs_cli.exe -x "show calls count" > testlog.txt
```

but I have to do this manually and it always overwrites the previous one. I need the script to do this automatically every 5s until I stop the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fs_cli.exe -x "show calls count" >> testlog.txt
```

(notice the additional `>`) will append text to the file instead of overwriting the file

You can write a loop using this kind of code in PS:

```
#never-ending loop, condition is always true
while($true) {

    #run a command (fs_cli.exe -x "show calls count" >> testlog.txt)
    #or maybe several
    date
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).LoadPercentage >> c:\cpu_usage.txt

    #sleep for 5 seconds
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Comment: This is great ! Thanks so much ! Any chance to include cpu usage in % into the code please ?

Comment: Amended my answer, but you could easily have found this out by yourself, as I did ^_^

Comment: You are the best. Thanks !